# Python REST-API with Flask-RestX and JavaScript REST-Client served together

Tags: python, rest, flask, swagger, flask-restx

I run this example: https://flask-restx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example.html
(A Python REST-API with Flask-RESTX)

### Code snippet

```
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app, ...)
ns = api.namespace('todos', ...)

@ns.route('/')
...
@ns.route('/<int:id>')
...
```

### Result

I get the following URLs for the REST-API:

http://127.0.0.1:5000 -> Swagger Documentation

http://127.0.0.1:5000/swagger.json

http://127.0.0.1:5000/todos/

[http://127.0.0.1:5000/todos/{id}](http://127.0.0.1:5000/todos/%7Bid%7D)

### Question

I would like to implement a Webclient with Javascript, which should be reached under following URLs:

http://127.0.0.1:5000 -> index.html

http://127.0.0.1:5000/style.css

http://127.0.0.1:5000/app.js

The URLs for the REST-API should change to:

http://127.0.0.1:5000/api -> Swagger Documentation

http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/swagger.json

http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/todos/

[http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/todos/{id}](http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/todos/%7Bid%7D)

How can I expand the example to generate the wanted URLs?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have gotten an answer by now. I often clone the below github project for flask restx boilerplate. It is designed as a rest boilerplate to help get you up and running.

https://github.com/cosmic-byte/flask-restplus-boilerplate

The templates and static files can be added to the application and to the controllers to host the pages. Added the below documentation for the static pages. Every this should be there to get you running with a full site

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/static/

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap flask-restx application with flask.Blueprint to move swagger logic under a specific url_path.

The following example shows how this can be achieved:

```py
import flask
import flask_restx


APP = flask.Flask("my-app")
api_bp = flask.Blueprint("api", __name__, url_prefix="/api")

API = flask_restx.Api(api_bp)
APP.register_blueprint(api_bp)


NAMESPACE = API.namespace("todos")


@NAMESPACE.route("/")
class TODOSAPI(flask_restx.Resource):
    def get(self):
        return ['todo-1', 'todo-2']
```